# AutoComplete Mac OS X doesn't operate normally

Tags: mac, terminal, autocomplete

In my Working Directory  I have 3 files and directories names:
`Applications`, `Application`, `Appendix.txt`
When I am trying to do AutoComplete by hitting <kbd>tab</kbd> it misbehaves

I type `App` and hit <kbd>tab</kbd>, AutoComplete gives me `Applications` instead of stopping and allowing me to choose one of the three entries (when hitting another tab).

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Q1: Are you using Apple's built-in Terminal or something else?

Comment: Q2: Which shell are you using? bash or something else?

Comment: Q3: Do you have any customization to your shell config (ie .bash_profile or .bashrc)?

Comment: Hello, Q1: Yes Apple's built-in Terminal.          Q2: using bash             Q3: Yes, but it was long time ago, It was working just fine until today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great, I found the answer to this issue. Anyway, all you have to do is to edit a file called `.inputrc` in the home directory `~`.

So here are the steps:

```
nano ~/.inputrc
```

In the file Delete the following line: `TAB: menu-complete`.

The file should contain only the following lines:

```
set completion-ignore-case on
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
```

Then restart the terminal.

And voilà.